# Integration with a matrix as the the integrand

Tags: vector-calculus

How can I calculate the following integral (wisely) in Mathematica?

$\qquad \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 \mathbf{A}\,d\alpha\,d\beta\,d\gamma$,

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector defined as:

$\qquad \left( \begin{array}{c}
-\cos(\beta)*\cos(\gamma)*\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)*\sin(\gamma) \\
\cos(\alpha)*\cos(\beta)*\cos(\gamma)-\sin(\alpha)*\sin(\gamma)  \\
\cos(\gamma)*\sin(\beta)  \end{array} \right)$

and how when $\mathbf{A}$ becomes a 3x3 matrix (all elements depend only on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$).

Comment: "Wisely" is a bit ambiguous, since it is obvious the integral should be `0` because both `Sin` and `Cos` have period `2Pi` and every component is integrated over `2Pi`. By the way, it seems you have never tried to integrate anything with _Mathematica_.

Comment: Code, at least for the matrix, would make it convenient for those who are interested to test their ideas.  Otherwise people who don't have time might just skip it.

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
A = {-Cos[b] Cos[g] Sin[a] - Cos[a] Sin[g],Cos[a] Cos[b] Cos[g] - Sin[a] Sin[g], Cos[g] Sin[b]};
Integrate[A, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, Pi}, {g, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> {0, 0, 0}

If A is a matrix just replace the vector with it.